# Excel - how to produce array of non-adjacent cells for use in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate a score for each record in a dataset.  The score is arrived at by adding together a series of smaller scores determined by a multiplier and an associated figure.

If the associated figures were a simple range from inside the dataset I would use a `SUMPRODUCT` to multiply the two arrays and sum it up.  However, due to the fact that some of the figures need to be derived I would need to be able to construct an array out the various figures.

I'm hoping to get a formula like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(multipliers,--([a],[b],min(.6,([a]+[c])/[d]),[f]="abc")
```

This could be performed by creating a number of check columns and referring to those but can anyone suggest how to perform this calculation elegantly within a single cell as my SUMPRODUCT's second argument won't work?

Here is a downloadable copy of the spreadsheet https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40423572/sumproduct%20example.xlsx

[image: A single calculation]
[image: The formulae used]

Comment: The second argument of example SUMPRODUCT doesn't work.  Using the fx wizard, it's "Invalid".  Trying to specifically reference a few table columns instead (`=SUMPRODUCT(multiplier,--([a],[b],[c],[d]))`) results in a VALUE error. I'd like to know how to overcome this issue and/or how to use another function that can do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So, to be clear, you're trying to replace your mult/value/result table and total with a single formula (for each row in table1) ?

Comment: Yes. This would enable performing the calc for many records instead of just one.

Comment: I want `=SUMPRODUCT({1,3,4,5},{30000,10000,0.6,1})` where the second lot are either column values or derived values

Comment: @Raystafarian, I have added a link to a copy of the spreadsheet

Comment: Why use sumproduct if you are not looking at other rows?  i.e. use a regular formula like =1*[@a]+3*[@b]+4*(MIN(0.6,([@a]+[@c])/[@d]))+5*IF([@f]="abc",1,0)

Comment: Good suggest @Madball73 .  I was being too complicated about it - so long as my multiplier values are fairly stable, this is a good way to go.  Would you like to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it for each row only, you don't need/want SUMPRODUCT.

Just use:

```
=1*[@a]+3*[@b]+4*(MIN(0.6,([@a]+[@c])/[@d]))+5*IF([@f]="abc",1,0)
```

You can substitute 1/3/4/5 with cell references/names if needed.